# How to go a specific position?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

Hi i want to parse a text from an html document could you please give me ur lights on how to do it? and how to reach the specific text??

```
<div style="margin-top:10;">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><input type="hidden" value="courseMain.asp?mnuID=diloseis;showDil&amp;prID=36&amp;prog=true&amp;studPg=1&amp;" name="courseLinkHid" id="courseLinkHid" />
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" width="95%" align="center" id="mainTable">
    <TR>
        <TD><img src="Images/dilwsi.gif" align="absmiddle"></img><span class="tablebold"> Προβολή δηλώσεων</span></TD>
        <TD align="right"><span class="underline" style="cursor:pointer" onClick="window.open('stud_NewClass.asp?mnuid=diloseis;newDil','_self')">TEXT1</span></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD align="right" height="15px" colspan="2">
            <hr size="1">
            </hr>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD align="right" height="15px" colspan="2"><span style="cursor:pointer" onClick="javascript:CollapseStClass('1');"><img src="images/expand16.gif" /> TEXT2</span>
            <span style="cursor:pointer" onClick="javascript:CollapseStClass('0');"><img src="images/collapse16.gif" /> TEXT3</span>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR bgcolor="#FFFAF0">
        <TD width="100%" colspan="2">
            <DIV>
                <SPAN class="tablebold" style="cursor:pointer;background-color:#FFFAF0;vertical-align:top" onclick="javascript:showMe();"><img title="Λεπτομέρειες" src="images/minus.gif" /></SPAN><span class="tablebold" style="background-color:#FFFAF0;"> 
                2013-2014
                ΕΑΡ</span>
                <div style="display:">
                    <TABLE width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <TD class="italicHeader" nowrap="true">Κωδικός</TD>
                            <TD class="italicHeader" width="80%">Τίτλος</TD>
                            <TD class="italicHeader" width="5%" valign="top">Εξάμ.</TD>
                            <TD class="italicHeader" width="5%" valign="top">ΔΜ</TD>
                            <TD class="italicHeader" width="5%" valign="top">Ώρες</TD>
                            <TD class="italicHeader" width="5%" valign="top">Τύπος</TD>
                            <TD class="italicHeader" width="5%" valign="top">Βαθμός</TD>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="25">
                            <TD nowrap="true" class="bottomborderLight">TEXT5</TD>
                            <TD width="80%" class="bottomborderLight"><span onMouseOver="underline('1','red')" onMouseOut="underline('0','#003399')" class="underline" style="cursor:pointer" onClick="window.open(document.getElementById('courseLinkHid').value + 'courseID=' + window.event.srcElement.parentNode.childNodes[1].value + '&amp;orID=' + window.event.srcElement.parentNode.childNodes[2].value,'_self')">TEXT6</span><input type="hidden" value="470-2206" /><input type="hidden" value="-1" /></TD>
                            <TD width="5%" valign="top" class="bottomborderLight">Β</TD>
                            <TD width="5%" valign="top" class="bottomborderLight"> 4</TD>
                            <TD width="5%" valign="top" class="bottomborderLight">3</TD>
                            <TD width="5%" valign="top" class="bottomborderLight">Υ</TD>
                            <TD width="5%" valign="top" class="bottomborderLight"><span class="redFonts">**TEXT7**</span></TD>
                        </tr>
                    </TABLE>
                </div>
            </DIV>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</table>
```

i want to reach to text7
i put a picture of where i want specifically to go because i messed up with the code sample:
[pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/is1xprr2dgo8mj0/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doc.select("#mainTable td .redFonts");
```

This selection Query should work

Comment: Thanks :) a lot i will try it i think thats the correct answer!!